# Windows Phone 7 with mDNS / Bonjour browser

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to migrate an iPhone App into WP7 App - which I need to browse local service and resolve it's IP (mostly DHCP) address and set connection.

I cannot find any sample of Bonjour / mDNS code for .NET C#, the closest I found is the Zeroconfig project http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/ ... it's going to be quite some works to put this on WP7.

Anyone has tried to implement this on WP7?

Answer (score 0):

At present there's no access to low level networking capablities.

Any networking capability is exposed by way of HTTP at the moment.

Comment: How about uPnP? since it's MSFT they should support it?

Comment: As far as programmatic network interfacing goes for 3rd party apps, it's all http.